# select from multiple child tables in sql

Tags: mysql, database, join, inner-join

I have 3 table, 1 is the parent table and 2 child tables.
 1st table contains all the order numbers and other 2 child table contains the order details for the order numbers

example 
table **Order_master**

```html
order_id | order_date | order_status
-------------------------------------
   1     |  20-10-15  |  pending
------------------------------------
   2     |  10-11-15  |  closed
------------------------------------
   3     |  15-11-15  |  closed
------------------------------------
   4     |  25-12-15  |  pending
------------------------------------
   5     |  27-12-15  |  closed
------------------------------------
```

Child Table **order_detail**

```html
-------------------------------------
id       | order_id | client_name
-------------------------------------
   1     |     1    |  Abc company
------------------------------------
   2     |     3    |  Test company
```

Child Table **order_detail_cc**

```html
-------------------------------------
id       | order_id | client_name
-------------------------------------
   1     |     2    |  XYZ company
------------------------------------
   2     |     4    |  A2 company
------------------------------------
   3     |     5    |  B2 company
------------------------------------
```

now i want to get the results as

```html
-------------------------------------
order_id | order_date | client_name
-------------------------------------
   1     |  20-10-15  |  Abc company
------------------------------------
   2     |  10-11-15  |  XYZ company
------------------------------------
   3     |  15-11-15  |  Test company
------------------------------------
   4     |  25-12-15  |  A2 company
------------------------------------
   5     |  27-12-15  |  B2 company
------------------------------------
```

please help

Comment: what if there are many entries in details or details_cc for one order? what if there are entries in both tables for one order?

Comment: What kind of query have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[MySQL Union](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html) manual

```
SELECT Order_master.order_date, Order_master.order_date, u.client_name
FROM Order_master
JOIN (
    (SELECT order_id, client_name
    FROM order_detail)
    UNION
    (SELECT order_id, client_name
    FROM order_detail_cc)
) u ON Order_master.order_id = u.order_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  order_id, order_date, client_name
FROM    order_detail
JOIN    order
USING   (order_id)
UNION ALL
SELECT  order_id, order_date, client_name
FROM    order_detail_cc
JOIN    order
USING   (order_id)
```